# Movie with an amulet and a princess who asked three questions from her suitors

Tags: story-identification, magic, urban-fantasy

Saw this movie more than 20 years ago, I can't remember much more about it than this:

- it was in color, but it's at least 30 years old, maybe even 40
- it was about a princess
- people wanting to marry her had to answer 3 questions,

  - if they got 1 wrong, they turn into stone or freeze or something like that.
- there was some kind of witch involved
- live action
- there was some old man with a staff who at the end of the movie put some amulet in his chest or something like that.

**What is the name of this movie?**

Comment: For questions related to movies, there's another stackexchange: http://movies.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is [Vandronik](http://german.imdb.com/title/tt0246305/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) (1990).

> *After his father's death, young John is forced to leave his home.
>   Penniless but light of heart, he sets out to see the world. Having
>   found refuge in a church one stormy night, John prevents two criminals
>   from robbing the corpse of a man who is to be buried the following
>   day. From that night on, a mysterious stranger accompanies the young
>   man on his travels. One day, the two companions arrive at a court
>   ruled by a heavy-hearted king. They are told that the king's beautiful
>   daughter is heartless and cruel. **Whoever wishes to marry her must
>   answer three questions; whoever fails turns to stone.** The princess,
>   however, is under the spell of the evil Magnus, who lives in a
>   mountain grotto and can metamorphose himself at will. Magnus refuses
>   to release his hold on the princess, since he draws his strength from
>   the life of her hapless suitors. Together with his companion, John
>   braves Magnus and his cohorts in his attempt to woo the princess. He
>   overcomes several ordeals with the help of his friend, but the final
>   ordeal is his to master alone.*

[image]

Comment: It was this one! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dude in the throne looks like John Goodman. Cannot unsee.

Answer (score 5):

Your question reminded me a lot of the story of [Turandot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turandot) - and there is, apparently, a [1987 movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0220822/) of this tale, and a [1983 TV movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0385301/), either of which might fit your timeline.

In the story, there is indeed a cruel princess in china, the named Turandot, who sets her suitors with three riddles, with those who failed being executed - the quote I recall is, "There are three riddles but only one death".  The main character, a prince, manages to guess the answer to each of the three riddles, and when she's horrified at being forced to marry him, he issues a counteroffer - that if she can find out his name, he will let himself be executed.  She has the whole kingdom looking for the answer, and tortures his slave girl to find his name (the girl refuses, and kills herself, because she is loyal and a bit in love with the prince).  In the end, the prince gives Turandot his name so she can make her own choice, and she chooses to name him her love (and marry him) instead of announcing that she had indeed found his real name and having him executed.  It looks like both movies were live action, and in color (at least, It looks that way from the listings I see).

Things that fit less well - I don't recall a character of a witch or a specific mention of an old man with an amulet, though there is a secondary female character of a slave girl (who gives advice and sacrifices herself for the prince), and either the ministers or the king might have some kind of amulet which I am unaware of.  It might not be the movie you were thinking of, if the witch and amulet were really central to your movie - but it looked similar enough I thought I'd offer this as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

"Clash of the Titans"(1981)?

It did have people turning to stone, but it was when they looked into the eyes of Medusa. Also when Perseus goes to this city, he finds that anyone who solves a riddle(can't remember if there were 3 of them), can marry the beautiful princess Andromeda. I believe it had some kind of connection to the no. 3, but I can't find the exact scene or anything on-line about this scene. I also seem to recall that if the suitor fails the question(s), they get burned alive?

Comment: I made the same guess, but the piece of jewelry is Calibos' ring, and there's only one question. Here's the clip - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIwBBVHpi-M